# How do I turn this SQL pivot into an inner join pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: Pupils, KS3Assessments and AssessmentSets.

- Pupils each have a StudentID, FName, SName etc.
- AssessmentSet contains the title of the assessment, the deadline, the year group that must complete it, etc.  New ones are created throughout the year, so their titles/ids can't be named explicitly in the SQL.
- KS3Assessments records each have a StudentID that refers to the pupil who
  completed the work, a SetID that refers to the relevant AssessmentSet record and an 'NCLevel' indicating the result that the pupil achieved.

I need a results overview table that looks like this:

```
 - StudentID ¦ FName ¦ SName ¦ Creative Writing #1 ¦ Novel Study ¦ Random Thingy Test ¦ etc. ¦ etc.
 - 072509273 ¦ Adam¦ Adamson¦ 5.5¦ 4.8¦ 6.5¦ etc.¦ etc¦
 - 072509274 ¦ Bob ¦ Bobson¦ 5.8¦ 5.2¦ 7.2¦ etc.¦ etc¦
```

... so that, at any time, a teacher can see what a pupil has achieved in whatever assessments they've done so far.

So far, using pivot, I've managed to get this:

```
 - StudentID, FName, SName, 147, 146, 154 (These numbers are the SetIDs) 
 - 072509273, Adam, Adamson, 5.5, 4.8, 6.5
 - 072509274, Bob, Bobson, 5.8, 5.2, 7.2
```

Here's my SQL.  I'd really appreciate any ideas about how to fix this and upgrade it to get the result that I'm looking for.  I suspect it will involve an inner join (or two), but I'm still having trouble getting my head around the pivot syntax.  Many thanks.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SetID) 
                from KS3Assessments
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentID, FName, SName' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select KS3Assessments.StudentID,
              Pupils.FName,
              Pupils.SName,
              KS3Assessments.NCLevel,
              KS3Assessments.SetID                                                                  
            from KS3Assessments inner join Pupils on KS3Assessments.StudentID = Pupils.StudentID
            where Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
        ) x
        pivot (max(NCLevel) for SetID in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: It looks like your query already incorporates a join to `Pupils` that gets you the names, what's not working at this point?

Comment: What's wrong with your PIVOT above?

Comment: In what context is the result of the sql being used?  I'm asking because (and I think you know this), what you got is pretty hacky.  Maybe there's another way around this?

Comment: Yeah, it's mostly working fine - I just want the column headings that currently show up as their SetIDs, taken from the KS3Assessment records, to show their Titles, taken from the AssessmentSet table.

Comment: I don't see a AssessmentSet in the example above. Is that the INNER JOIN you are missing?

Comment: It's a vb.net app that fellow teachers use to record assessment results.  I've been asked to give them a grid that shows the results that all pupils in a given class have received for all assessments that have been conducted so far.  I've reached the limits of my SQL knowledge, so I've been picking over SO answers to get this far...

Comment: Yes, I don't know where to fit it in.

Comment: I would recommend looking into SSRS if you have the time. You could create a report grouped columnwise and write normal sql statements instead of that above :).

Comment: I'm investigating.  Thanks for the heads-up.  Can I take it that this isn't solvable by other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Title) 
                from AssessmentSet 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentID, FName, SName' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select KS3Assessments.StudentID,
              Pupils.FName,
              Pupils.SName,
              KS3Assessments.NCLevel,
              AssessmentSet.Title
            from KS3Assessments inner join Pupils on KS3Assessments.StudentID = Pupils.StudentID
        inner join AssessmentSet on KS3Assessments.SetID = AssessmentSet.SetID
            where Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
        ) x
        pivot (max(NCLevel) for Title in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks - this has has got me closer.  I actually (foolishly) simplified my problem a little bit - the title for an assessment set is actually stored in the 'AssessmentSuperSet' table.  By switching 'SuperSetID' for 'Title' in your code, I'm now closer to what I'm after because I get the SuperSetIDs.  Two remaining issues: I now get all of the SuperSetIDs that exist (including ones that the pupils in that class would not do - assessments for other year groups) and I need to get at the nice user-readable title which is AssessmentSuperSet.Title.  Do you reckon you could help me further?

Comment: Yeah, being dense.  Mostly worked it out now.  I just need to cut out Sets that this class can't complete, but I think that's a new question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
             SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(title) 
             FROM AssessmentSet
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
          ,1,1,'')
SET @query = N'
SELECT StudentID, FName, SName, ' + @cols + ' 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        K.StudentID,
        P.FName,
        P.SName,
        K.NCLevel,
        A.title                                                                 
    FROM KS3Assessments K
    INNER JOIN Pupils P ON K.StudentID = P.StudentID
    INNER JOIN AssessmentSet A ON K.SetID = A.SetID
    WHERE Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
) x
PIVOT (MAX(NCLevel) FOR title IN (' + @cols + ') 
) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caffc/12)

Sample output:

```
| STUDENTID | FNAME |   SNAME | CREATIVE WRITING #1 | NOVEL STUDY | RANDOM THINGY TEST |
|-----------|-------|---------|---------------------|-------------|--------------------|
|  72509273 |  Adam | Adamson |                 5.5 |         4.8 |                6.5 |
|  72509274 |   Bob |  Bobson |                 5.8 |         5.2 |                7.2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how tables are related but give below try.

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Title) 
                from KS3Assessments 
                inner join AssessmentSet on KS3Assessments.SetID = AssessmentSet.SetID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT StudentID, FName, SName' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select KS3Assessments.StudentID,
              Pupils.FName,
              Pupils.SName,
              KS3Assessments.NCLevel,
              KS3Assessments.SetID ,
              AssessmentSet.Title                                                                
            from KS3Assessments inner join Pupils on KS3Assessments.StudentID = Pupils.StudentID
            inner join AssessmentSet on KS3Assessments.SetID = AssessmentSet.SetID
            where Pupils.GroupDesignation = ''8KF/En 14/15''
        ) x
        pivot (max(NCLevel) for Title in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: the pivoting is now by title (@cols), so you need to remove the SetID from the main query or the result will be wrong